# Lifetime of global scalar variable (pointer)

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

```
// Complete Header File (myheader.hpp)
#pragma once
void fun();

// Complete Cpp File
// I don't think removing `static` from the following line changes storage duration nor lifefime
#include "myheader.hpp"
#include <iostream>
static auto num = new int(10);
void fun() { std::cout << *num; }
```

Imagine that many other files include `myheader.hpp` and call `fun`. In particular, inside destructors of static global variables. Can this lead to undefined behavior? (ie, dereferencing `num` when its storage has been freed by the compiler when the program starts to terminate!)

Edit:
The type of `num` is `int*`. So I don't think it will ever be destructed. So the order of calling destructors not being specified is not a problem here. There are two/three problems, and I would like to know if any of them is a possibility:

1. The memory block pointed to by `&num` changes. So `*num` would become undefined.
2. The memory block pointed to by `num` is freed, so `*num` would become undefined.
3. The content of `*num` would change, so `*num` is defined but has a different value.

Comment: can some unknown code cause UB? sure

Comment: There's nothing here that will delete the `new`ed `int`, so undefined behavior due to this is somewhat technical, but, in general, yes, this is called "Static Initialization Order Fiasco". Google it.

Comment: If the other global variables are in other files, then it's unspecified which order things get destructed. So it would be unspecified whether `num` was destructed before or after those other variables. If the order was wrong then you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @john `num` is of type pointer. So I am not sure what you mean by "`num` was destructed ..."

Comment: @Koosha All objects have destructors, even if those destructors do nothing. And using an object in any way after is has been (notionally) destructed is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @john So what is the destructor of an object of type `int*`? Do you mean, there is a destructor, it does nothing, but after it has been called, any attempt to read `num` (not even `*num`) is undefined?

Comment: I'm going to be a contrarian here - I believe this example is well-defined. The lifetime of an object with trivial destructor ends when its storage is deallocated, which for an object with a static storage duration happens when the program ends. It's actually a reasonably common technique to implement singletons - allocate one on first use, and then never deallocate it at all. Now, if `fun` is ever called in a constructor or initializer of a static or global variable, *then* you'd have undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The question explicitly says "... call `fun`. In particular, inside destructors of static global variables". Does that make it an undefined behavior? From the beginning of your answer, I thought you would say no. But the end of your answer suggests yes (undefined). Also, your explanation says it is ok for **any** other destructor to call `fun`, since (after `num` has been assigned a value) `*num` is always well defined.

Comment: @Koosha Calling `fun` in destructors of global variables is OK. Calling `fun` in constructors or initializers of global variables is not OK, because those may run before `num` is initialized with `new int`. Before thus initialized, `num` is null, and then `*num` in `fun` would exhibit undefined behavior. Once initialized, it'll remain correctly initialized until the program terminates. I'm not sure which part of my first comment could be construed to state otherwise.